# Can't get rid of padding in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uitextview

I'm trying to remove a sizable top padding that seems to be applied to my UITextView.

I've added this to ViewDidLoad:

```
_tweetTextView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
_tweetTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

But this is what the UITextView looks like

[image]

What is going on here?!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the View Controller treating the Text View as a Scroll View (which, at its core...it is). As such, it will automatically add the inset to the top to prevent the content in the Text View from initially showing up behind the navigation bar.

In order to get rid of this, you have to suppress this behaviour by the view controller. There are two ways you can do this.

1. In your `viewDidLoad`, add `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` or
2. In `Interface Builder`, click on the problem View Controller, and under the `View Controller` headline in the inspector, uncheck `Adjust Scroll View Insets` under `Layout`.

If you would like a more in-depth explanation, there is a nice discussion on [makagio's tech journal](http://mokagio.github.io/tech-journal/2015/01/23/ios-unexpected-table-view-header-padding.html), and inside the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with the parent View Controller.  I had to uncheck "under top bars" and "under bottom bars"

[image]